# How to update multiple Rows In Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

basically I want to update this table in one go or bulk update.

I wanted to update the "image_id" field on this table.

[image: Table]

This is my code in the Controller

```
public function storebulk(Request $request,$id)
  {
     $ids= ['8','9','10']; //sent from the front-end

     $barcode = Barcode::where('id', $ids)->update(['image_id'=>$id]);

     return 'Done';
  }
```

but for some reason it doesn't work. if anyone can point out what I missed here it will be great.

thanks

Comment: you should give `whereIn` a try

Comment: should be `Barcode::whereIn('id', $ids)->update(['image_id'=>$id]);`

Comment: thanks guys.. i did'nt think of that.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `whereIn`:

```
public function storebulk(Request $request, $id)
{
     $ids= ['8','9','10']; //sent from the front-end

     $barcode = Barcode::whereIn('id', $ids)->update(['image_id'=>$id]);

     return 'Done';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel, If you want to update multiple rows or get multiple rows of same type always use `whereIn`.

The Docs Define `whereIn` as -
The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array

```
public function storebulk(Request $request,$id)
  {
     $ids= ['8','9','10']; //sent from the front-end

     $barcode = Barcode::whereIn('id', $ids)->update(['image_id'=>$id]);

     return 'Done';
  }
```

Link to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#:%7E:text=whereIn%20/%20whereNotIn%20/%20orWhereIn%20/%20orWhereNotIn)